# Highlighting a UIView similar to UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView with a number of subviews and a Tap gesture recognized associated and I want to mimic it having a 'touch' effect. That is, when the tap happens, I want to show the container view to have a different background color and the text of any subview UILabels to also look highlighted.

When I receive the tap event from UITapGestureRecognizer, I can change the background color just fine and even set the UILabel to `[label setHighlighted:YES];`

For various reasons, I cannot change the UIView to UIControl.

But if I add some UIViewAnimation to revert the highlighting, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

```
    - (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
      [label setHighlighted:YES]; // change the label highlight property

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.20 
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         [containerView setBackgroundColor:originalBgColor];          
                         [label setHighlighted:NO]; // Problem: don't see the highlight reverted
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {                         
                         // nothing to handle here
                     }];    
}
```

Comment: Why not just make it a `UIButton`?

Comment: Because it is not a codebase I own and there's other dependencies so I have to leave it as UIView.

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/mta452/UIView-TouchHighlighting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

setHighlighted isn't an animatable view property. Plus, you're saying two opposite things: you setHighlighted to YES and NO in the same breath. The result will be that nothing happens because there's no overall change.

Use the completion handler or delayed performance to change the highlight *later*.

EDIT:

You say "tried both but neither worked." Perhaps you need clarification on what I mean by delayed performance. I just tried this and it works perfectly:

```
- (void) tapped: (UIGestureRecognizer*) g {
    label.highlighted = YES;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        label.highlighted = NO;
    });
}
```

The label must have a different `textColor` vs its `highlightedTextColor` so that something visible happens.

Comment: Tried both but neither worked.. I may have to figure out an another creative way to do this or go about rewiring the existing codebase to use UIControl.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

**You can use a custom view** like this for example:

```
class HighlightView: UIView {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.alpha = 1.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self.alpha = 0.5
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.alpha = 0.5
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.alpha = 0.5
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Just play around with the duration and animations as you like. In the end you can use it instead of `UIView` and whenever you will click on it, it will change its `alpha` value so it will look like a highlight.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution is override tap gesture regognizer
like below:

**Swift 4.x**

```
class TapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var highlightOnTouch = true

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        if highlightOnTouch {
            let bgcolor = view?.backgroundColor
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveLinear], animations: {
                self.view?.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            }) { (_) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveLinear], animations: {
                    self.view?.backgroundColor = bgcolor
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: when is `highlightOnTouch` set to false?

Comment: `let gesture = TapGestureRecognizer( :_:)`



`gesture. highlightOnTouch = false`

Comment: oh, sorry, I was misunderstood. I thought it was a variable to reset the background color, but it just a variable to enable/disable this feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.7**

```
import UIKit

final class HighlightingTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    private(set) var viewToHighlight: UIView
    
    init(target: Any?, action: Selector?, viewToHighlight: UIView) {
        self.viewToHighlight = viewToHighlight
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.viewToHighlight.alpha = 0.7
        })
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.viewToHighlight.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4 and above

```
final class HighlightingTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    private(set) var viewToHighlight: UIView

    init(target: Any?, action: Selector?, viewToHighlight: UIView) {
        self.viewToHighlight = viewToHighlight
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        let xPosition = touches.first?.location(in: viewToHighlight).x
        let yPosition = touches.first?.location(in: viewToHighlight).y

        let width = 30
        let height = 30

        let view11 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: Int(xPosition!), y: Int(yPosition!), width: width,     height: height))
        view11.isHidden = true
        view11.backgroundColor = .darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        view11.layer.cornerRadius = view11.frame.height / 2
        view11.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.viewToHighlight.addSubview(view11)

        view11.isHidden = false
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            view11.removeFromSuperview()
        })

    }
}
```

use:

```
let tap = HighlightingTapRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.YourActionFunc(_:)), viewToHighlight: previewView)
previewView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```